# How to display PDF in Web browser using ServletOutputStream

Tags: jsf, servlets, pdf

I have been trying to display a pdf report in a web browser using ServletOutputStream. So far, I am able to download the file but I cannot get it to display in the browser. Here is my code

```
private void initReport()
{
    DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();

     try {
         jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getContext().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/testReport.jasper"), new HashMap(),connection.getConnection());

     } catch (JRException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(ReportBacking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }

}

public void showPDF()
{
    initReport();
     try {
         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)  getContext().getExternalContext().getResponse();

         httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
         httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=testReport.pdf");
         ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();

         JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,servletOutputStream);

         getContext().responseComplete();
         getContext().renderResponse();

     } catch (JRException | IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(CertificateApplicationAddBacking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       getContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Could not generate report")); 
     }
```

If I change the content-diposition to attachment. I am able to download the file.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it downloads or displays in the browser is out of your control.  Its a setting in the browser or in Acrobat, or a combination, which only the user can change (if they know how).

However, you could use a Flash/Silverlight app that let's you load a PDF into it, or find a way to use [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) by passing your PDF bytes from the server to PDF.js and having it render the PDF in the browser. Look at the examples page. Where they do:

```
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
  // you can now use *pdf* here
});
```

You can change 'helloworld.pdf' to the URL of your servlet.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it works perfectly in firefox but in chrome I am getting this error:                                             `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf`